# Can only one foreign key be displayed

Tags: dolphindb

When fj is fully connected, both the foreign keys of the left table and the right table will be displayed. How can I make it show only one foreign key?

```py
t1=table(1 2 3 3 as id, 7.8 4.6 5.1 0.1 as value)
t2=table(5 3 1 as id, 300 500 800 as qty)
fj(t1, t2, `id)
```

The result is as follows:

| id | value | t2_id | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.8 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 4.6 |  |  |
| 3 | 5.1 | 3 | 500 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 3 | 500 |
|  |  | 5 | 300 |

I need a result like the one showing below:

| id | value | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.8 | 800 |
| 2 | 4.6 |  |
| 3 | 5.1 | 500 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 500 |
| 5 |  | 300 |

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, nullFill!(t1.time, t2.time) means that if t1.time is a null value, it will be filled with the value of t2.time:

```py
t1 = table(1 2 3 3 6 as time, 1.1 2.1 3.1 3.1 6.1 as value) 
t2 = table(5 3 1 as time, 5.1 3.1 1.1 as qty) 
select nullFill(t1.time, t2.time) as time, value, qty from fj(t1, t2, `time) order by nullFill!(t1.time, t2.time)
```

See [nullFill!](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/n/nullFill!.html) for more detailed information.